# incorrect Data in graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have been trying to use the Beta Graph API endpoints to capture the activity reports for the various O365 workloads. We found that when we fetch the data for Skype for Business Activity data using the Graph API with date parameter its not fetching the correct user list.

As we know that a user has an activity on specific date but the Graph API is not returning the users activity report for that day: `/beta/reports/SfbActivity(view='Detail',Date='2017-07-25')/content`

We verified the data for the users activity by using the detail report for D90 period. This report has the users activity for the specific dates as last activity date.
`/beta/reports/SfbActivity(view='Detail',Period = 'D90')/content`